# If rpm install is running, wait until finished

Tags: rpm

We had troubles since our application run during rpm installation.

In the future we would like to know if the rpm command is currently installing rpm packages.

Maybe I am missing the matching keywords, but I could not find a way to detect this with my favourite search engine.

How to detect if a rpm install is currently running?

Answer (score 0):

I guess here must be some kind of lock file, but both `zypper` and `rpm` can be installing new packages; and they detect whether the other program is trying to do something. A very simplistic approach might be:

```
if pgrep rpm || pgrep zypper
then
    echo "won't run since rpms are being installed"
    exit
fi
```

Comment: Yes, this could work. But `rpm -qa` would be a false positive: There is a process called "rpm", but it does not do any installs.

Comment: agree... I said it is a very simplistic approach....